# If statement in django templates

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

```
def func_view(request,id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id, user=request.user)

    return render_to_response('post.html',
                              {'post': post},
                              RequestContext(request))
```

in my template:

```
 <div id="post-data">
                {{ post.name }} 

                {{ post.date }}
                {{ post.extra }}


            </div>
```

How to create something like this: If my `{{ post.extra }}` is empty in database -> displaying information "Extra is empty" ?

Comment: you might want to read the [django template reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [built-in helpers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if):

```
{% if post.extra %}
  {{ post.extra }}
{% else %}
  Extra is empty
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or use use filter [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#default):

```
{{ post.extra|default:"Extra is empty" }}
```